# Quicksort with insertsort

Tags: python

i have to make a program which prints the time for quicksort, but when the lenght of the list is smaller f.e than 500 it has to do insert sort, which i did in code right here:

```
c = 501
def quickSort(A, p, r):
if p < r:
    m = r - p + 1
    if m < c:
        insert_sort(A, p, r)
    else:
        # q to indeks dzielenia tablicy
        q = partition(A, p, r)
        quickSort(A, p, q)
        quickSort(A, q + 1, r)
```

but then, i have to compare the time for quicksort and insert_sort

```
start = time.time()
quickSort(A500, 0, 499)
end = time.time()
start1 = time.time()
quickSort(A500, 0, 499)
end1 = time.time()
print("Num of elements \n500             ", end - start, (end1 - start1))
```

But obv, the second one will be 0 because i already sorted it with insert sort. And i wonder how do change the code so it would once do insert_sorte and once quicksort

Answer (score 0):

You can use deepcopy to pass a copy of the list into the function. You can also try writing `A500[:]`, which makes a copy of `A500`, but python might duplicate it instead:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

start = time.time()
quickSort(deepcopy(A500), 0, 499)
end = time.time()
start1 = time.time()
quickSort(A500, 0, 499)
end1 = time.time()
print("Num of elements \n500             ", end - start, (end1 - start1))
```

This makes it so that you are not passing a duplicate of the original list, but a copy, which doesn't impact the original list.